# Why is my substitution for my integral wrong?

Tags: integration, substitution

Let f be a non-negative continuous function, and suppose that
$\int_1^{\infty} f(x) \,dx$ converges.
Show that $\int_1^{\infty} f(y^2) \,dx$ converges.

I substituted $x=y^2$ into the second equation, which led me to $$\int_1^{\infty} f(y^2) \,dx = \int_1^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{2x} \,dx$$, which means that $\int_1^{\infty} f(y^2) \,dx$ converges.

However, the answer provided was that $$\int_1^{\infty} f(y^2) \,dx = \int_1^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{2{\sqrt{x}}} \,dx$$ While the integral still converges, I'm concerned over why my substitution was wrong. I had assumed that $\frac{dx}{dy} = 2x$, hence substituting that into the equation, but I'm not sure how I would get ${2\sqrt{x}}$.

Could someone please help?

Comment: If $x=y^2$ then the substitution should be "$dx = 2y dy$" which (with the substitution $y=\sqrt{x}$) can be rewritten as "$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \, dx = dy$."

Comment: the question doesn't have any sense, as if $x=y ^2$ then $\int_{1}^{\infty }f(x)dx=\int_1^{\infty }f(y^2)dx$

Answer (score 2):

The goal of substitution is to replace ***all** occurrences* of $y$ in the *integrand* and *differential* with expressions of $x$.

So you do not want $y$ to occur anywhere in the right hand side.   To do this you replace $y:=\surd x$ and $\mathrm d y:=\mathrm d x/(2\surd x)$ .

$$\begin{align}\int\limits_1^\infty f(y^2)\,\mathrm d y\quad&=\quad\int\limits_1^\infty \dfrac{f(x)}{2\surd x}\,\mathrm d x&\qquad&{\begin{split}y&:=\surd x\\\mathrm d y&:=\mathrm d x/(2\surd x)\end{split}}\end{align}$$